# Merging multiple dataframes that all have a indexed ['Date'}

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dataframes all have a `['Date']` column set as the index

```
data_frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
```

I would like to merge them all on the index I found the below code but it obviously wont work in my case because it only merges 2 dataframes.  Is there anyways to do it with a list in one step?

```
final_df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner'), data_frames)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't pass dataframes to `pd.merge` in lambda function

```py
final_df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_index=True), data_frames)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [functools reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) and [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

The reduce(func, seq) function is used to apply a function passed in its argument to all of the list elements in data_frames.

Since the Date column is set to the index a list comprehension is used to .reset_index() back to a column. Finally set Date column back to index after the merge.

```
data_frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]

df_final = reduce(
    lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on="Date", how="inner"),
    [x.reset_index() for x in data_frames]
).set_index("Date")
```

Comment: this doesnt work because the 'Date' column is set as the index

Comment: list comp to reset index. see edit

Comment: Could you add an explanation of how this works and format the code so it's easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[1,2,3]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[3]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[1,2,3,4]})
df5 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[4]})
data_frames = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5])
print(data_frames)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up doing it in multiple lines and it worked, but wanted to know if there was a one line solution.

```
final_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
final_df = pd.merge(final_df, df3, left_index=True, right_index=True)
final_df = pd.merge(final_df, df4, left_index=True, right_index=True)
final_df = pd.merge(final_df, df5, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```